# Are light sources like Brightbloom Seeds permanent?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When using brightbloom seeds, you can light up dark areas.  Are these lights permanent?

Assuming they are not:

- What would cause them to despawn (timer, distance, other)?
- Is the despawn condition the same for all light source items, such as big brightbloom seeds?

Comment: From experience, they definitely aren't permanent. No hard evidence, but I'm guessing the blood moon resets them

Comment: I've accidentally hit the large ones "unharvested" while fighting a monster and then come back at least a couple game-days later and saw they were still lit after traveling a good distance away.  I wonder if the fact that I didn't pick them up had an effect?  Maybe if they get activated while still in their own original spawn point?    Maybe user-placed brightblooms will despawn normally?

Comment: Probably not enough for a full answer, but I’ve seen Little Frox enemies eat my placed Brightblooms (which despawns them)

Comment: I know they carry over when you save and reload...

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tearsofthekingdom/comments/13huvz2/brightbloom_despawn/):

> There is a world limit on Brightbloom plants. I didn't count, but I'm guessing in the 200s. Once you place the first plant that exceeds the limit, it despawns the first plant you ever placed, and so on.
> If they are permanent outside of this (which appears to be the case), this means that, once you are at the world limit, there will always be that many Brightbloom plants in your world, somewhere.
> There is also a density limit. You can only place 3 place within a certain radius (maybe 2-3 meters in-game).

And also, as suggested by @scohe001:

> It also seems that the Little Frox enemies in The Depths will actually eat brightbloom seeds you place down.

Comment: Big Froxes eat them too. At least the big seeds, I don't think I've ever shot a small one near a big Frox.